# How to make chromeapp open in its window instead of a new tab of browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am new to chrome app development,i am almost ready with my firstApp,but when i click on the installed icon it opens my app to new tab instead of opening in a window.
Please suggest me the cause of and the solution of this.

**mainfest.js**

```
{
    "name"             :"my first App",
    "description"      :"Test description",
    "version"          :"0.1",
    "manifest_version" :2,

    "app" :{
        "launch": {
          "web_url": "http://localhost/chromeapp/"
        },
        "scripts"  : ["background.js"]
    },
    "icons" :{"16":"img/amoeba.png","128":"img/amoeba.png"}               
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    "bounds": {
      "width": 1000,
      "height": 650
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Remove `"launch"` key. Also make sure to look at the official app samples: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples

Comment: on removing the launch i am getting and error : Failed to load extension from: /var/www/html/chromeapp
Either 'app.launch.local_path' or 'app.launch.web_url' is required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved,need to modify my file.
**Mainfest.js**

```
{
    "name"             :"my first App",
    "description"      :"Test description",
    "version"          :"0.1",
    "manifest_version" :2,
    "offline_enabled": true,                     //added
    "app" :{
        "background": {                        //added 
        "scripts"  : ["background.js"]
    }
    },
    "icons" :{"16":"img/amoeba.png"}               
}
```